# Angularjs - $watch issue

Tags: angularjs, watch

I got this error and i dont know what im doing wrong
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.userFormData.cpr')

Can some one help me out, because im not sure what im doing wrong, the error is there as soon i load the page

```
 $scope.$watch(function () {
                return $scope.userFormData.cpr;
            },
            function (cprValue) {

                console.log(cprValue);

                //For at scriptet ikke skal faile første gang det bliver loadet
                //tjekker vi om medlemmet har skrevet noget i cpr feltet
                if (cprValue === undefined) {
                    return false;
                }

                //Hent brugerens input og split dem op
                var cpr = cprValue.toString();

                //Hvis cpr undeholder en streg -

                var dd = +cpr.substr(0, 2); // 01
                var mm = +cpr.substr(2, 2); // 02
                var yy = +cpr.substr(4, 2); // 90

                //Calculate if 90 is > 50
                if (yy > 50) {
                    var year = yy + 1900;
                } else {
                    var year = yy + 2000;
                }

                //Sæt fødselsdags datoen sammen så momentJS forstår det
                var final = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + year;

                //Beregn datoen og split resultatet op så vi kun får fødselsdags tallet
                var alder = moment(final, "MM/DD/YYYY").fromNow().split(" ")[0];

                //Vi clear ageToYoung feltet hvis det har været udfyldt
                //og disabler andenBetaler vinduet igen
                $scope.ageToYoung = "";
                $scope.hideSecondpayer = true;


                //Hvis personen er mellem 15 og 18 år så vis andenBetaler boksen
                if ((alder >= 15) && (alder <= 18)) {
                    $scope.hideSecondpayer  = false;
                    $scope.hideRegnrBarn    = true;
                    $scope.hideKontonrBarn  = true;

                } else if (alder <= 14) {

                    //Personen er ikke gammel nok, og vi skriver det derfor til kunden
                    $scope.ageToYoung = "Du skal minimum være 15 år gammel";
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning it in anonymous function, apply `$watch` directly on scope objects-

```
$scope.$watch('userFormData.cpr',
            function (cprValue) {

                console.log(cprValue);

                //For at scriptet ikke skal faile første gang det bliver loadet
                //tjekker vi om medlemmet har skrevet noget i cpr feltet
                if (cprValue === undefined) {
                    return false;
                }

                //Hent brugerens input og split dem op
                var cpr = cprValue.toString();

                //Hvis cpr undeholder en streg -

                var dd = +cpr.substr(0, 2); // 01
                var mm = +cpr.substr(2, 2); // 02
                var yy = +cpr.substr(4, 2); // 90

                //Calculate if 90 is > 50
                if (yy > 50) {
                    var year = yy + 1900;
                } else {
                    var year = yy + 2000;
                }

                //Sæt fødselsdags datoen sammen så momentJS forstår det
                var final = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + year;

                //Beregn datoen og split resultatet op så vi kun får fødselsdags tallet
                var alder = moment(final, "MM/DD/YYYY").fromNow().split(" ")[0];

                //Vi clear ageToYoung feltet hvis det har været udfyldt
                //og disabler andenBetaler vinduet igen
                $scope.ageToYoung = "";
                $scope.hideSecondpayer = true;


                //Hvis personen er mellem 15 og 18 år så vis andenBetaler boksen
                if ((alder >= 15) && (alder <= 18)) {
                    $scope.hideSecondpayer  = false;
                    $scope.hideRegnrBarn    = true;
                    $scope.hideKontonrBarn  = true;

                } else if (alder <= 14) {

                    //Personen er ikke gammel nok, og vi skriver det derfor til kunden
                    $scope.ageToYoung = "Du skal minimum være 15 år gammel";
                }

            });
```